# How to get each edittext value from the listview while click inside listview button

Tags: java, android

I have listview. Each list contain checkbox,edittext and two button in my custom adapter. When i click plus button,I want to increase corresponding position edittext value. I don't know how to get particular position edittext value from the listView while click plus button.

Please anyone help me!

Here my code...

```
public class MenuListCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> Amtlist = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;
TextView listItemText;
TextView listAmtText;
EditText qty;
CheckBox checkBox;
ImageView plus;
ImageView minus;

public MenuListCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, ArrayList<String> Amtlist, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.Amtlist = Amtlist;
    this.context = context;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;



    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_custom_fragment, null);
    }
    listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_list_item_string);
    listAmtText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_amt_list_item);
    qty = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chckbox);
    plus = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.add);
    minus = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.minus);

    qty.setText("1");
    qty.setTag(position);
    listItemText.setText(list.get(position));
    listAmtText.setText(Amtlist.get(position));

    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String value = // How to get particular position edittext value 
            int count = Integer.parseInt(value)+1;
            Log.d("value", String.valueOf(count));
            qty.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

[image: My page here :]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: create new arraylist same as name and price and one plus minus click store specific position value in that list

Answer (score 1):

Try this to avoid ListView duplicates, because ListView does not guarantee uniqueness of items you are added there, Android reuse UI objects.

**Create a new class with the elements of the list:**

```
public class YourObject {
    private String listElement;
    private String amListElement;
    private int count;

public YourObject(String listElement, String amListElement) {
    this.listElement = listElement;
    this.amListElement = amListElement;
    this.count = 1;
}

public String getListElement() {
    return listElement;
}

public void setListElement(String listElement) {
    this.listElement = listElement;
}

public String getAmListElement() {
    return amListElement;
}

public void setAmListElement(String amListElement) {
    this.amListElement = amListElement;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
```

}

**Pass one ArrayList with the object(model) to the adapter:**

```
public MenuListCustomAdapter(ArrayList<YourObject> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}
  //....  
    qty.setText(list.get(position).getCount());
    qty.setTag(position);
    listItemText.setText(list.get(position).getListElement());
    listAmtText.setText(Amtlist.get(position).getAmListElement());

    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int count = list.get(position).getCount()+1;
            list.get(position).setCount(count);
            Log.d("value", String.valueOf(count));
            qty.setText(""+count);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

**Get particular position edittext value:**

```
list.get(position).getCount();
```

If you want to get the value of the edittext may you ill get the errors that i said at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

add `android:onClick="plushClicked"` in XML where your `+` located at.

Then create a method `plushClicked`

```
public void plushClicked(View v) 
    {

        //get the row the clicked button is in
        LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();

        TextView child = (TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(0);
        Button btnChild = (Button)vwParentRow.getChildAt(1);//where your child belongs to
       EditText et = (EditText) vwParentRow.getChildAt(2);
       et.getText().toString(); //here is your value of editText

    }
```

have a look at [this](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.it/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html) for more reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can set current view to button in adapter's `getView()` method and in `button.setOnClickListener()` you can get this view and do whatever you want. Use `setTag()` and `getTag()`.

Example:

In `getView()` of adapter:

```
btnPlus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlusdessert);
btnPlus.setTag(R.integer.btnplusview,convertView);
```

Button's onClickListener()

```
btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View tempView =(View) v.getTag(R.integer.btnplusview);
                EditText qty = (EditText)tempView .findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                qty.setText("sometext");
```

Now you have complete view of row layout and you can get other textview or button or whatever with tempView.

Suppose you click + button of 2nd row,then entire rowview of 2nd row will be inflated in tempView and you can get 2nd row's edittext and change it's value as per your requirement.